# Approach to extract meaning from sentence NLP

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, nltk

What I want to know is what the best approach would be to extract meaning from a text. I gave [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/book/ch01.html) a read, and it did give me some good information on the basics of NLP.

I'm new to nlp, so I'm having a tough time deciding what my direction should be. After reading the NLTK text, here's what I'm thinking what would solve my problem:

Here is my ideal goal with example sentences:

**Input:**

> Do X on 8/29/2018 until 9/12/2018 (every Wednesday) and 9/10/2018 (Monday)

**Output Part of Speech tag in bold (At least what I invision):**

> Do X on 8/29/2018(***Date***) until(***Range***) 9/12/2018(***Date***) (every(***Frequency***) Wednesday(***Day***) and 9/10/2018(***Date***) (Monday)(***Day***)

Next, I would loop through the part of speech tags and chuck the text. My hope is after chunking of the text appropriately, I would then need to do some additional processing in order to figure out what the user exactly wants. Here's what I'm thinking the output would be after a successful  meaning extraction from the sentence :

> 8/29/2018 - 9/12/2018, Wednedays
>
> 9/10/2018, Monday

I realize that finding days of the month, days and dates, etc can be easily found through a regular expression.

But my issue is that the NLTK method ***nltk.pos_tag*** method would not work for me. (For those who aren't familiar, the method is a part of speech tagger tagging words likw noun, verb etc.) I would most likely have to customize my own ***pos_tag*** method?

So here's my question. Is tagging each tokenized word first, then chunking the sentences from the tags considered best practice to extract meaning?

I'm guessing I would need some sort of AI classification to learn the chunking part so that in the future I can extracting meaning from more than one sentence.

Is my approach sane? Have I gone mad? :)

Answer (score 2):

While you haven't gone mad (probably :), this is a very general question which (probably) will be tagged soon by an admin as unfitting for SO, because it is too broad. 'Extracting the meaning of a sentence' is something that basically everyone working in NLP is working on for decades already. Most (commercially/practically) viable ways of doing this exist only because their domain of application is relatively limited. Think a chatbot for hotel booking (with clearly definable slots for arrival/departure date, location, etc), a car navigation system allowing voice input ('I want to go to X, avoid highways'), etc.

Since your example output is targeted at dates and times, which indeed is not what a pos-tagger is meant for, some temporal analysis module could be better for your use case. Just one toolkit that comes to mind is https://github.com/HeidelTime/heideltime, which uses the TimeML scheme (which is also something you may want to have a look at) to indicate concrete points in time, and also time intervals, and tries to normalise this to machine-readable points in time.

What else in terms of NLP modules you need very much depends on your input. If it's relatively strict (the number of different ways of saying something is small), probably manually crafting a simple grammar is your best bet. Things easily get more complex however. 'Do X on Mondays from dd-mm-yyyy until dd-mm-yyyy' in natural language can equally well be expressed by 'Do X on Mondays, starting on dd-mm-yyyy, ending at dd-mm-yyyy'. It really helps knowing which language your users will use. An out-of-the-box package or toolkit to generally extract meaning from a sentence (for English, let alone for one of the other 6.000 or so officially acknowledged languages (whichever institution decides this) :) has yet to be discovered/developed.

Apart from NLTK (which I find very valuable for education purposes and ins relatively flexible to work with, but also is a bit outdated by now), you can check out https://spacy.io/. To some extent, it is meant to do the same things, but with more modern methods and data sets.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what you are looking for is not pos tagging, as pos tagging is meant as you said to decide if a word is a noun, verb etc. Your problem is an NER problem, that stands for Named entity recognition and that allows you to understand if a word or list of words are a place name, a person name, a hotel name etc..

There are many ressources, tutorials libraries (even in nltk [NLTK NER](https://spacy.io/api/entityrecognizer) and Spacy [Spacy NER](https://spacy.io/api/entityrecognizer)) that explain this problem.

Hope I have helped better orient you.

Best of luck ;)